# How to disable x-editable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

How can I disable the x-editable submit button?  I don't want it permanently disabled as upon other events, I will need to re-enable it.  Below is my attempt.

https://jsfiddle.net/fndnu5m0/1/

```
$(function() {

    $('#name').editable({
        type: 'text',
        title: 'Name',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        pk: 123,
        inputclass: 'autocomplete'
    }).
    on('shown', function(event, edit) {
        console.log('on', this, edit)
        $(document).find('input.autocomplete').val('')
        .parent().next().find('button.editable-submit').css('opacity', 0.3).off('click');
    });

});
```

Comment: can you explain how userflow is suppose to go, like do you want to let user click it once and then disable it

Comment: @MuhammadUmer  My ultimate goal is to use jQueryUI AutoComplete with x-editable.  I've almost implemented it at https://jsfiddle.net/fndnu5m0/.  If you see this fiddle, you will see that my userflow is to only activate the submit buttons after the user clicks an autocomplete item.  Thanks!

Comment: A better implementation of my previous attempt, but still doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/fndnu5m0/3/

Answer (score 1):

Bind a new click event to the element in question.  To re-enable the submit button, remove the event (not shown).  Don't know if this is the best option, and would like comments (or even markdowns if a good comment is provided with it).

https://jsfiddle.net/fndnu5m0/7/

```
$(function() {

    $('#name').editable({
        type: 'text',
        title: 'Name',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        pk: 123,
        inputclass: 'autocomplete'
    }).
    on('shown', function(event, edit) {
        console.log('on', this, edit)
        $(document).find('input.autocomplete').val('')
        .parent().next().find('button.editable-submit').css('opacity', 0.3)
        .bind('click',function(){return false;});
    });

});
```